# Blackberry/WebWorks app appears in small window at the top of the screen in simulator

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks, lungojs

I'm building an app for Blackberry using the WebWorks sdk for OS 7 & earlier. I am also using the latest Cordova/PhoneGap framework (2.8). Lastly, I am making use of the Lungo.js mobile framework for html developement.

The problem I have is a display issue. Upon deployment in the simulator, only part of the app appears at the top of the screen, roughly 5px in height.I have attached a screenshot of what is happening.[image]

I am wondering if it is a viewport issue. Here's a snippet of html code...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Is there something else I have left out or need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear your cache in the simulator

Comment: It worked! I went into the Webworks simulator and cleared the four files that are copied there when you run the command for the simulator. I also realized that there were four additional files from running the Cordova "example" project I had initially built to make sure I had all my files and settings in place. Once I deleted these files, cleaned the project and ran the simulator again all my chnages had taken effect!